# React Native WebRTC - DOMException

Tags: android, sockets, react-native, webrtc, voip

here's a thing, I am trying to make some simple "Viber like" app, all I need is VoIP "chat", and I tought it would be nice to use WebRTC for this,cuz why not (if you have anything better pls feel free to let me know), problem is i spent 5+ days trying to figure it out but I did not, I can't find any solution, and no matter what i do i get "DOMException" error.

I am using React Native:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "0.49.3",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.58.3"
  }
```

Here is some of my code:

```
// try: #1
getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
    .then((stream) => {
        console.log(stream);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })

// try: #2
getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
}, (stream) => {
    console.log(stream);
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
})

// try: #3
MediaStreamTrack.getSources((sourceInfos) => {
    console.log(sourceInfos);
    let videoSourceId;
    for (const i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (sourceInfo.kind == "video" && sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? "front" : "back")) {
            videoSourceId = sourceInfo.id;
        }
    }
    getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                minWidth: 500,
                minHeight: 300,
                minFrameRate: 30
            },
            facingMode: (isFront ? "user" : "environment"),
            optional: (videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [])
        }
    }, function (stream) {
        localStream = stream;
        console.log("Got Local Stream");
        callback(stream);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("Get LocalStream Fail: ", error);
    });
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the treatement of sourceInfos is not after the enumeration. You should call getSources().then(treatement of sourceInfos).

Anyway, consider [the deprecation of MediaStreamTrack.getSources](https://github.com/kdzwinel/JS-OCR-demo/issues/7)

Comment: thx for response, I'll try it later I am not able to do that now, but I thing I got sourceInfos, I mean I get array of devices and stuff, anyway ty I will test it right away and let you know

Comment: Any updates on this one, I am having the exact same issue. Were you able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the application's access rights to the camera and recording sound (both in the manifest and in the settings)